# When should `std::atomic` be used?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, std, data-race

I'm working on a small project of mine that involves the use of multiple threads.

The C++ STD library offsers different ways to prevent `undefined behavior` or `data races` from accessing the same memory block:

- `std::atomic`
- `std::mutex` with `std::lock_guard`

Now, from my understanding, you can use both of them and the result would be pretty much the same. Both locks a resource when used by a thread and prevents another from accessing it.

Though, my question is:

**When should I prefer to use `std::atomic` over `std::mutex` and when should I use `std::mutex` over `std::atomic`?**

---

Take this simple class as an example. I have three way of using this class to prevent `data races`:

#### Using `std::atomic<Buffer>`

```cpp
class Buffer {
  private:
    int m_Data;
  public:
    void Write(int data) {
      m_Data = data;
    }
    int Read() {
      return m_Data;
    }
}

int main() {
  std::atomic<Buffer> buffer;
  buffer.store(Buffer());

  RunThread_0(&buffer, 10);

  RunThread_1(&buffer, 20):
}
```

#### Using class member `std::atomic<int> m_Data`

```cpp
class Buffer {
  private:
    std::atomic<int> m_Data;
  public:
    void Write(int data) {
      m_Data.store(data);
    }
    int Read() {
      return m_Data.load();
    }
}

int main() {
  Buffer buffer = Buffer();

  RunThread_0(&buffer, 10);

  RunThread_1(&buffer, 20):
}
```

#### Using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`

```cpp
class Buffer {
  private:
    int m_Data;

    std::mutex m_DataMutex;

  public:
    void Write(int data) {
      const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_DataMutex);
      m_Data = data;
    }
    int Read() {
      const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_DataMutex);
      return m_Data
    }
}

int main() {
  Buffer buffer = Buffer();

  RunThread_0(&buffer, 10);

  RunThread_1(&buffer, 20):
}
```

---

Note: *`RunThread_0` and `RunThread_1` do what you'd expect: they both call the `Buffer::Write` method to change the value of member `Buffer::m_Data`.*

---

#### Final thoughts

I always used `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`, but I feel like `std::atomic` is 'easier' to use as you don't have to worry about missing a lock, whereas if you use `std::mutex` you can accidentally miss an `std::lock_guard` statement and thus making a data race possible.

So, is there an advantage in using `std::atomic` over `std::mutex` or is it just a design matter?

Comment: In my opinion, C++ `std::atomic` makes sense only for data types that your CPU can process by atomic instructions. Typically, these consists of fundamental integer (including character and Boolean) and pointer types.